# How does silent access token work for azure b2c

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to understand the authentication process for Azure B2C. It is my understanding that up to 50k authentication per months are free and you pay more if it goes over 50k.

I am developing two applications. One for front-end and another for back-end that will use Azure B2C to authenticate users.

Here is my scenario.

1. Users will go to UI portal to login with their social accounts.
2. Users can access back-end resources by making API call based on their permissions.

So it is my understanding that when you login to UI using your social account you receive an access token, which is one authentication in B2C. If they want to access back-end resources from API, it requires you to acquire access token by making another request as shown [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/blob/master/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/Controllers/HomeController.cs). Below is the example code that acquires token silently.

```cs
// Retrieve the token with the specified scopes

var scope = AzureAdB2COptions.ApiScopes.Split(' ');

string signedInUserID = HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserID, this.HttpContext).GetMsalCacheInstance();

ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(AzureAdB2COptions.ClientId, AzureAdB2COptions.Authority, AzureAdB2COptions.RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(AzureAdB2COptions.ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);

AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scope, cca.Users.FirstOrDefault(), AzureAdB2COptions.Authority, false);

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, AzureAdB2COptions.ApiUrl);

// Add token to the Authorization header and make the request

request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

My question is, when login in to UI using your social account and accessing back-end resources with another silent request. Does it count as 1 authentication? Or it counts as 2 authentication in Azure B2C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After your web application handles the authentication response, the `ConfidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync` method [retrieves the access token from Azure AD B2C and then writes it to a token cache](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/blob/85effe880ef7a580b71ad59a7be24a4291634e87/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet/OpenIdConnectOptionsSetup.cs#L103), which is implemented by the `MSALSessionCache` class.

Before your web application invokes your web API, the `ConfidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenSilentAsync` method reads the existing access token from the token cache and only requests a new access token from Azure AD B2C if:

1. The access token doesn't exist in the token cache;
2. It is about to expire; or
3. It has expired.

If the existing access token is read from the token cache, then you aren't charged for the issued token.

If a new access token is requested from Azure AD B2C, then you are charged for the issued token.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to worry about the number of authentications. If the same user connects 100 times, it still represent 1 MAU (Monthly Active User).